# How to resolve Terminal error/messaging somehow related to rbenv

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, osx-elcapitan, rbenv

I've been receiving the following error/messaging right after I start up Terminal. This started happening after multiple attempts to install sass (which is another issue on its own).

I've since uninstalled rbenv.
I'm running osx el capitan.

```
-bash: ‘export: command not found
-bash: /Users/JO/.bash_profile: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /Users/JO/.bash_profile: line 5: `‘eval “export PATH="/Users/JO/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}" export RBENV_SHELL=bash source '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash' command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null rbenv() { local command command="${1:-}" if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then shift fi case "$command" in rehash|shell) eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";; *) command rbenv "$command" "$@";; esac }”’'
```

I'm way over my head with Terminal issues. So, any help on this is much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: It looks like your `.bash_profile` file has been modified in some way in the installation of rbenv, and this modification was incorrect or incomplete. Are you able to edit `/Users/JO/.bash_profile` in a text editor despite the terminal issues? While it may not be a full solution, it may help to comment out the offending line (adding a `#` to the start of line 5)

Comment: @ZoeyHewll Appreciate you taking a look. Follow-up question for you. Why would commenting out the offending line be the correct action over deleting the line altogether? Sorry, I'm not well versed in the command-line at all and just looking for clarification. Thanks!

Comment: I would be cautious deleting the line entirely as some parts may end up being useful, but we know from the error that at least one part is causing a problem. Commenting it out means that the line is ignored, but you're not committing to removing it, in case you do want to go back and keep some of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is said (**Basic Github checkout, part 2**) to you to copy and past one of the following options, according to your running terminal:

For Bash: `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

For Ubuntu: `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc`

For **Zsh**: `echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Checking your log above, I saw you use `'eval`, which you must delete, and let just "one of the options above".

Alternatively, you may run the rbenv doctor to see what you missed:

`curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash`

Do not forget to open a new terminal to see your changes running.